# Regrading automating RESTASSURED POST API request with Authorization

Tags: java, rest-assured, api-authorization

Greetings!

I am working on automating dummy POST API request with Authorization.

Please check below details for the same,

**Code:-

```java
RestAssured.baseURI="http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/users";
String jsonBody = "{\"tourist_name\":\"Mike\",\"tourist_email\":\"mxyz5676@gmail.com\",\"tourist_location\":\"Paris\"}";    
String token="433tc02b-b5c1-4bd8-836a-618cdc31c492";
    
    
Response response = RestAssured.given()
             .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
             .header("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3")
             .header("Accept", "*/*")
             .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
             .body(jsonBody)
            .post("http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/users");

int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
System.out.println("Response Code: " + statusCode);

System.out.println("Response Body: " + responseBody);
```

After execution, received 401 Response and expected response is 201.

This same API is working with POSTMAN and received 201 response.

Please check below POSTMAN screenshots for API collection details,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmtC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsahF.png)

Please guide me how to resolve this?

I tried above code but getting 403 response code.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why have you got tag references randomly in your post? Please don't do that. Also, please remove fluff like "Hi Team" and "Greetings" - it's unnecessary, and reduces the useful information shown in the questions list.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. Basically, 401 means you're not authenticated, your token is invalid. 403 means you're authenticated but don't have permissions needed to do the action.